# Getting an array_merge error on account verified event using Laravel 8 and Pusher

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I am using Pusher 5 running on Laravel 8, I was trying to broadcast user verified event. However, when I verify my account I get the following error:

[Pusher error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsNDf.jpg)

My listener code is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Events;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;

class Verified implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $afterCommit = true;

    /**
     * The verified user.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail
     */
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('users');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'account-verified';
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['id' => 'heya'];
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

try `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server ^4.1`,
at least this works with the `beyondecode/laravel-websockets`,
not sure about the official pusher server